# How to use term edit page instead of view page?

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms

On the terms list page,  each term is linked to the view page (i.e. `term/[tid]`). As I don't have any details in the view page, I would like to link it to edit page. (.i.e `term/[tid]/edit`). How to alter this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways we could achieve this:

Option 1: Introduce a [route subscriber](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/altering-existing-routes-and-adding-new-routes-based-on-dynamic-ones) in a custom module with below code:

```php
    $route = $collection->get('entity.taxonomy_term.edit_form');
    $collection->add('entity.taxonomy_term.canonical', $route);
```

This code would replace the edit_form to the canonical route.

**Note**: Might need to update the local task to remove the `view` tab as it is confusing to see the edit form in the `view` tab (as below).

[image]

Option 2: Extend `Drupal\taxonomy\Form\OverviewTerms` form and overwrite `buildForm` method and use `$term->toUrl('edit-form')` as below:

```
      $form['terms'][$key]['term'] = [
        '#prefix' => !empty($indentation) ? $this->renderer->render($indentation) : '',
        '#type' => 'link',
        '#title' => $term->getName(),
        '#url' => $term->toUrl('edit-form'),
      ];
```

However, it might not be a good idea considering how complex `buildForm` method is and the effort to keep up with any core changes.